# Adding Matlab plots to a template Book with no errors?

Tags: pgfplots, errors, templates

I am working with a template available online i.e. https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/phd-mphil-thesis-of-university-of-cambridge
I am trying to add Matlab figures using tikz. Before, doing so I used to have like 4 minor errors. I followed the same way to do so as in 
http://www.howtotex.com/packages/beautiful-matlab-figures-in-latex/

I added the userpackages as in

```
\usepackage{pgfplots,amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
```

In the main thesis.tex. But now when I am compiling , it works okay, however,there are lots of minor errors (136) things that were okay are not any more. What did I do wrong to cause all this mess?

Comment: 1) No need to add packages more than once. 2) It's very hard or impossible to guess the exact cause of a mess when all we know is that there is one. What is the first error you get? Adding those two packages to the template is not enough to produce any errors at all, so there is some other code you have added that is the problem. Try to make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and add that to your question.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I am getting "You have requested document class 'Classes/CUEDthesisPSPDF'.

Comment: THe template is bad, that is the result. ou can savely ignore it. Nothing to do with figures, graphics or tikz, just the decision of the author to *not* fix stuff and risk confusing users.

Comment: @Johannes_B is there a way of doing things easily and professionally as in this template (but simpler and less intimidatingly)

Comment: Using the standard `report` class with just the stuff you really need might be best.

Comment: If you insist on using a *template*, you might try out [MDT](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis), but please don't blame me if it fucks up ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B Alright thank you for that... I will try it but I already did lots of achievements in the current template... So I will not blame you ... no worries about that ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39787/discussion-between-johannes-b-and-rsc05).

Answer (score 1):

I am forever thankful to both @johannes_B and @Torbjorn. Again, I would never have gone around it if it was not for their help. The problem I was finding was how to write ideas found online on a template. It seems that I was writing every user packages in the main.tex when I should have written it in a particular file in that e main.tex.  After I had done this, it seems that I was defining same user packages more than once in a document.

```
Option clash for package color 
Option clash for package natbib 
Option clash for package graphicx

@rsc05  loads  which probably loads , and the clash is because you have . Remove the latter altogether, and add  to the class options, i.e.
```